# How to get session data from node backend to Angular UI?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, session, express

I'm facing an issue in getting user data stored in **req.session** in backend of node REST API where I'm storing logged in user data inside of **req.session**.
But on fetching data from backend I'm not getting user data but when I'm doing same thing with POSTMAN I'm easily able to get those user data from req.session.

**qa.service.ts**

```
getQuestions(){
           return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/questions').map(
               res => {
                   console.log(res.json());
                   const data = res.json().questions;
                   let questions = data.map(data => {
                        data.description = (data.description) ? "":data.description;
                        return new Questions(data._id,data.title,data.description,data.author,data.countVote,data.date,data.answers);
                   });
                   this.Questions = questions;
                   return this.Questions.slice();
            }
       );
    }
```

**questionController.js**

```
exports.getAllQuestions = async(req,res,next) => {

    try{
        const questions = await Question.find();
        const user = req.session.user;
        res.json({questions,user});
        return;
    }catch(error){
        res.json({error:"Something went wrong."});
    }  

};
```

Comment: did you login from the browser? it sounds like you have the session cookie in postman but not the browser

Comment: I try to login with angular and I'm getting the session data but when I move to another route the session data is no more available to work.Is there is any different logic for creating auth based app in REST API.

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/token-based-authentication-with-angularjs-nodejs--cms-22543 I read this article and got the point that session based authentication will not work in REST API.